# DataTable sort test question

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datatable

I was asked this question recently in a test, which I didn't pass.  For the life of me, I couldn't spot what the problem was.  It's probably something really obvious as well, but even a colleague of mine couldn't spot it either.  The best I could come up with was issues with bottlenecks and naming inconsistencies of parameters! I blame it on the fact I've not done any vb.net for years, I've been doing C# mostly these days :)

```
Private Function sorttable(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal sorttype$, ByVal sort_direction$) As DataTable
    Dim dv As DataView
    Dim dt2 As DataTable
    dt2 = dt.Clone
    dt2.Merge(dt)
    dv = dt2.DefaultView
    dv.Sort = sorttype & " " & sort_direction
    Return dv.ToTable()
End Function
```

The question: This function, although it will successfully sort a datatable, has a major problem with it. What is the problem? Re-write the function in either C# or VB.Net using LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataTable is cloned and then merged with it own clone? Very strange..

Answer (score 0):

in c# i use

use an typed dataset 
create a datatable in precising type of data

```
for example i have create a dsAppointment

     DsAppointment dsAppointmentTmp = new DsAppointment();
     DsAppointment dsAppointment = new DsAppointment();
    //add all appointment
     dsAppointmentTmp.Appointment.AddAppointmentRow(name,start,end,body)
    //use select(filter,sort(name of columns)
    DataRow[] rows1 = dsAppointmentTmp.Tables[0].Select(string.Empty, dsAppointmentTmp.Tables[0].Columns[1].ToString());

                foreach (DataRow thisRow in rows1)
                {
                        dsAppointment.Tables[0].Rows.Add(thisRow.ItemArray);

                }
//return dsAppointment sorted
                return dsAppointment;
```